# How to echo XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml

How to print an XML file to the screen in PHP?

This is not working:

```
$curl = curl_init();        
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories');   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
$result = curl_exec ($curl);   
curl_close ($curl);    
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
echo $xml;
```

Is there a simple solution? Maybe without SimpleXML?

Comment: XML is a string based format. SimpleXML converts XML to PHP Objects for easier manipulation in PHP. 

If you want to display XML, just echo the XML string, and like mentioned, don't forget to add the correct HTTP Response Headers. This is what instructs the HTTP client to treat the file as an XML file.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use HTTP URLs as if they were local files, thanks to [PHP's wrappers](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php)

You can get the contents from an URL via file_get_contents() and then echo it, or even read it directly using readfile()

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://example.com/rss');
echo $file;
```

or

```
readfile('http://example.com/rss');
```

Don't forget to set the correct MIME type before outputing anything, though.

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

Comment: To echo the XML contents inside a HTML file, I have to use 
`echo htmlentities($file)`
in order to display the raw XML (tags and content). Is there a better way?

Answer (score 18):

Here's what worked for me:

```
<pre class="prettyprint linenums">
    <code class="language-xml"><?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("example.xml"), ENT_QUOTES); ?></code>
</pre>
```

Using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) will prevent tags from being displayed as html and won't break anything. Note that I'm using [Prettyprint](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) to highlight the code ;)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the **asXML** method

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

You can also give it a filename

```
$xml->asXML('filename.xml');
```

Comment: Does this add the header? `header('Content-type: text/xml');`

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
echo(header('content-type: text/xml'));
```

Comment: Confirming this worked on a very large xml document.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to print the raw XML you don't need Simple XML. I added some error handling and a simple example of how you might want to use SimpleXML.

```
<?php 
$curl = curl_init();        
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories');   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
$result = curl_exec ($curl);   

if ($result === false) {
    die('Error fetching data: ' . curl_error($curl));   
}
curl_close ($curl);    

//we can at this point echo the XML if you want
//echo $result;

//parse xml string into SimpleXML objects
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

if ($xml === false) {
    die('Error parsing XML');   
}

//now we can loop through the xml structure
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    print $item->title;   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Am I oversimplifying this?

```
$location = "http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories";
print file_get_contents($location);
```

Some places (like digg.com) won't allow you to access their site without having a user-agent, in which case you would need to set that with ini_set() prior to running the file_get_contents().

Answer (score 4):

To display the html/xml "as is" (i.e. all entities and elements), simply escape the characters **<**, **&**, and enclose the result with **<pre>**:

```
$XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <foo>ó</foo>
    <bar>&#xF3;</bar>
</root>';

$XML = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $XML);
$XML = str_replace('<', '&lt;', $XML);
echo '<pre>' . $XML . '</pre>';
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <foo>ó</foo>
    <bar>&#xF3;</bar>
</root>
```

Tested on Chrome 45

Comment: $XML = str_replace('>', '&gt;', $XML);

Answer (score 0):

**If anyone is  targeting yahoo rss feed may benefit from this snippet**

```
<?php
    $rssUrl="http://news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories";
    //====================================================
    $xml=simplexml_load_file($rssUrl) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    //====================================================
    $featureRss =  array_slice(json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml ),  true ), 0 );
 /*Just to see what is in it 
use this function PrettyPrintArray() 
instead of var_dump($featureRss);*/

    function PrettyPrintArray($rssData, $level) {
    foreach($rssData as $key => $Items) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $level; $i++)
    echo("&nbsp;");
    /*if content more than one*/
    if(!is_array($Items)){
    //$Items=htmlentities($Items); 
    $Items=htmlspecialchars($Items);
    echo("Item " .$key . " => " . $Items . "<br/><br/>");
    }
    else 
    {
    echo($key . " => <br/><br/>");
    PrettyPrintArray($Items, $level+1);
    }
    }
    }
    PrettyPrintArray($featureRss, 0);
?>
```

You may want to run it in your browser first to see what is there and before looping and style it up pretty simple

To grab the first item description

```
<?php
    echo($featureRss['channel']['item'][0]['description']);
?>
```

[You can see a demo here](http://tubentertain.com/breaking-news/)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<?php
$XML = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- Your XML -->
";

header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
echo ($XML);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to add to your apache `.htaccess` file the following line after `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

and then simply having a file `sitemap.php` in your root folder that would be normally accessible via `http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap.xml`, the default URL where all search engines will firstly search.

The file `sitemap.php` shall start with

```
<?php
//Saturday, 11 January 2020 @kevin

header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

<url>
  <loc>https://www.yoursite.com/</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-08T13:06:14+00:00</lastmod>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>


</urlset>
```

it works :)