# Print xml with php

Tags: php, xml

I have this php code

```
    <?php
    $status_code=1;
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
    echo "<response>\n";
    echo "\t<status>$status_code</status>\n";
    echo "\t<time>" . time() . "</time>\n";
    if ($status_code == 1) {
            echo "\t<message>\n";
            echo "\t\t<author>Vlad</author>\n";
            echo "\t\t<text>Ova e poraka</text>\n";
            echo "\t</message>\n";
    }
    echo "</response>";
    ?>
```

Why I don't get the printed xml code in browser?

Also is it good practice to create ajax requests by printing the xml code directly in php or should I use some xml php function to create xml code?

I wanted to create a chat system by using jquery, ajax, php and mysql using this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/), but I get error that the above printed xml is not well formed

Comment: Try to avoid asking two completely different questions in one. It's much more useful to have them treated separately and therefore answered separately.

Comment: mmmm ok :) will post with ajax in other question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to echo xml file in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199595/how-to-echo-xml-file-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others have said, you need to give the browser a header to let it know how to display the page.

As for xml functions, have a look at the PHP [SimpleXMLElement](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Answer (score 3):

Try viewing your source, the xml is there but just not visible. Your browser will try to show the page as HTML, since you dont supply the correct headers. Since there are no tags, you wont see anything.

You should send the correct headers, as such:

```
header('content-type: text/xml')
```

Comment: Just to point out, the headers should be modified before any output to the page (so at the start of your script in this case).

Comment: And when thats not possible, you could use `ob_start`. However do try to send them at the top of the page.

Comment: Ok. with header works  but only when I remove the line  echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";   When this line exist I get this error XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity

Answer (score 2):

you have to put header (to let the browser know how to render the display):

```
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
```

Comment: also try the content type as: application/xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to use proper content-type, as the others have said.
I recommend you to use [XMLReader](http://php.net/xmlwriter).
Or if you want a n easier way, then try to use [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) string syntax with sprintf and htmlspecialchars to encode values with characters that have special meanings in XML (like <>&)