# Line breaks in XML not showing in browser but OK in view source

Tags: xml

I have generated an XML file that and one of the nodes contains data that I need to be rendered in a specific way with line breaks/new lines:

> This should be the first line
>   this should be the second line

When I load the XML in browser and view source it looks spot on, I can copy and paste the data with the structure maintained. In the browser however it is rendered as:

> This should be the first line  this should be the second line

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show your XML and XSL transform and output HTML.  Unless you take specific steps (inserting `<br>`), what you show is exactly what's supposed to happen.

Comment: Hi Jim Not using XSL at all, just simply displaying the XML in browser so any markup won't help on this occasion

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print xml with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267460/print-xml-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in XML that would assist you with formatting text in the browser. If you want to format XML data for viewing in the browser you should transform the XML into HTML and apply the approriate HTML tags that will format the text as you want it to appear.

Comment: Thanks pmartin, so If I wanted to provide someone with the XML they couldn't just copy and paste, they would need to develop their own routines to retrieve the data in the correct format?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. Where would someone copy/paste your XML from/to? When you talk about displaying something in the correct format - what does that mean?

Comment: I need to get to a situation whereby someone visits a URL and the XML is returned and displayed. They may need to take the data returned  and use it for a number of reasons. At the moment the formatting means it is incorrect and unusable as the returns need to remain in place

Comment: Further to my last comment, using the XML data as data transfer is fine, I have other ways round it but wondered if anyone could suggest a workaround

Comment: And that's basically what my answer is stating. If you want to display the XML data with formatting, use XSL to transform the XML into HTML (with the appropriate tags added in during the transform process) so that the resulting HTML displays the information how you want it to look on the web page.