# How to display XML data in HTML format complete with line breaks

Tags: php, email, simplexml, cpanel, cdata

When performing a *fetchautoresponder* call to cPanel, it returns the results in a CDATA block. When it is converted to SimpleXML for extraction, the results are fine except for the message body, which does not display the line breaks. Here's the snippet:

```
    $xmlapi = new xmlapi($ip);
    $xmlapi->set_output("xml");
    $xmlapi->set_port(2082);
    $xmlapi->password_auth("root", $root_pass);
    $params = array('email'=>$sEmail); 
    $cpResponse = $xmlapi->api2_query("root", "Email", "fetchautoresponder", $params);
    $xml_object = simplexml_load_string($cpResponse); 

    foreach($xml_object->data as $key=>$value) 
    { 
        echo "sender: ".$value->from."<br>";       //properly formatted name
        echo "subject: ".$value->subject."<br>";   //properly formatted subject
        echo "contents: ".$value->body."<br>";     //correct text but missing line breaks
    }
```

1. Is there another way to extract the results from the CDATA block that would display the line breaks?
2. Might there be another SimpleXML function that could display the value with line breaks?
3. Is there any other format for *$xmlapi->set_output()* that might solve this issue?

The data is already formatted with line breaks - otherwise it would not be possible to add the line breaks manually because there would be no way of knowing where to place the line breaks.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it strips the linebreaks? See as well [Line breaks in XML not showing in browser but OK in view source](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9809782/367456)

Comment: Hello hakre. What I meant was it does not display the line breaks. I'm very sure it's there because cPanel saves these autoresponders fully formatted. So, how could I get them to display properly?

Comment: Press CTRL+U in your browser. A new tab will open. Locate your output. Do you see the line breaks there?

Comment: Yes; it's formatted as it should be. How would I get the same output on the browser?

Comment: by using the right HTML tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre - PRE stands for preformatted. Or by using the right style-information which you can set via style-sheet-rules.

Comment: I read somewhere that replacing **&#10** and **&#xa** in the XML string with html line breaks would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: that is referring to something different (but also line-break related). you have a *display* problem, the line-breaks are in there, you're just not yet able to display them. You need to change the way you display those. HTML does normalize white-space and line-breaks are part of that. See as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: Sorry for all those modern links, here is one that just explains how it works with spaces and line-breaks in HTML. HTML is what you use to influence the display inside the browser: http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/whitespace.html

Comment: You're a genius, hakre; the **pre** tags did the trick. Now I only have to figure out how to track down those line breaks and replace them for formatted output. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to mark your suggestion as the answer. The css tag **pre-wrap** seems to be the way to go. Thank you, once again.

Comment: no problem. and nice to read you've now got some options on your hands. this btw. is not only a thing with XML, this is more generally about how to display or encode data with/in HTML.

Comment: I'll make a note of that. Thank you.