# How to make server response in XML

Tags: android, xml

I am using wordpress in my website. I want the response from server to be xml response. I came to know that if i use JSON API plugin then i will get json response from server. Right now i am getting html response from server. How to get XML response from server is there any plugin?

Comment: HTML is a particular format of XML, could you clarify your question? Maybe adding some code examples.

Comment: Just i need a plugin from which i can get xml response from server. so that i can parse that response in my android app

Comment: What I'm saying is you can parse HTML like an XML file. What you are looking for is probably a wordpress plugin which will spit out the information you wish without the standard HTML information. What kind of information are you trying to access? Database information, lists?

Answer (score 0):

take a Look here [How to echo xml file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199595/how-to-echo-xml-file-in-php). I think that is you want to do.
Hope it will helps you.

XML parser: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: Any plugin from which response from server would be xml? so that i can use xml to parse in my android app

Comment: I don't know what do you mean. Do you mean a plugin for php to echo the xml or plugin for Android to parse it?

Comment: here an example of Android parser: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/