# Php echo xml file

Tags: php, xml, echo

I've had this issue with an XML File i've been trying to echo out using PHP Without making 1 long line of text.

I run this code first to create my XML page, of all the products in my database:

```
<?php
$cfg = Array();

$cfg['db_host'] = '***';
$cfg['db_user'] = '***';
$cfg['db_password'] = '***';
$cfg['db_name'] = '***';

mysql_connect($cfg['db_host'], $cfg['db_user'], $cfg['db_password']);
mysql_select_db($cfg['db_name']);

unset($cfg);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Artikelen");

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $draw = $xml->addChild('draw');
   $draw->addChild('Product_Id',$row['Pr_Id']);
   $draw->addChild('Product',$row['Product']);
   $draw->addChild('Prijs',$row['Prijs']);
}

$fp = fopen("Artikelen.xml","wb");
fwrite($fp,$xml->asXML());
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Then i run this code from another file to show the `.XML`:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("Artikelen.xml");
print_r($xml);
?>
```

What this shows is:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [draw] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Product_Id] => 1 [Product] => Pizza Margherita [Prijs] => 7.00 )))
```

Times 11 in 1 long line, since i have 11 products. I've tried some things as:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("Artikelen.xml");

echo $xml->Product_Id . "<br>";
echo $xml->Product . "<br>";
echo $xml->Prijs . "<br><br>";
?>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

This is my first time working with XML files, so it might be a very simple solution.

Thanks in Advance!, If you seem to miss information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with print_r(), just echo pre tags before and after.

eg:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("Artikelen.xml");
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: This looks cool, is there also a way to remove the tags and only show the information, however this might look even better.

Comment: Not with print_r() - it's effectively a dump of the object.  You'll need to loop through, and echo each attribute you want in the format you would like.

Answer (score 1):

No need to re-invent the wheel.  Echo file_get_contents(), as in the below solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1199643/2257899

Edit:

If you look at your print_r() results, you'll see it contains an array.  Try:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("Artikelen.xml");

echo $xml["Product_Id"] . "<br>";
echo $xml["Product"] . "<br>";
echo $xml["Prijs"] . "<br><br>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this at least got rid of all the tags, but is there an easy way to <br> after every line and 2 <br> after the price of each product?

Comment: Thanks! I will check it first thing tomorrow morning

Comment: This didn't work, i will accept your other answer since it improved alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can display xml using asXml method:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("Artikelen.xml");
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: Thanks, this at least got rid of all the tags, but is there an easy way to <br> after every line and 2 <br> after the price of each product?