# How to get an XML and integrate it into own website

Tags: php, xml, api

I once was a Web-Designer who knew HTML/CSS. Now I'm a 3D animator, but I want to get back into the Web-Developer world.

But there's so much new to learn. E.g. flat file cms. Wow!

But my question for now is how I read an API, create the right PHP file to pull an XML file and put that data onto a web page.

Specificially I'm interested in this mobile.de API:
http://services.mobile.de/manual/search-api.html

And it seems that this is the XML that I need:
http://services.mobile.de/schema/ad-1.0.xsd

What are the next steps to get this beginner's project going?

I guess I need some sort of PHP file that uses GET and some sort of authentication. How can I test, if and what will come back?

And how do I use the pulled information to put in into a new page?

Or is my thinking all wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Ben

Comment: Sign up with the api if you have not already done so to get a `key` for the api and use `curl` to send your requests. The curl request will return something - hopefully xml if there were no errors - process that response using DOMDocument

Answer (score 0):

Little bit you can understand through this post and answers on this post:
[How to echo xml file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199595/how-to-echo-xml-file-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using already created library, please check : [**PHP Curl Class**](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class)

Taken from the readme:

> PHP Curl Class is an object-oriented wrapper of the PHP cURL extension that makes it easy to send HTTP requests and integrate with web APIs.

And this code snippet (also taken from the readme) could be your starting point:

```
$curl = new Curl();
$curl->setBasicAuthentication('username', 'password');
$curl->setUserAgent('');
$curl->setReferrer('');
$curl->setHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
$curl->setCookie('key', 'value');
$curl->get('http://www.example.com/');

if ($curl->error) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $curl->errorCode . ': ' . $curl->errorMessage;
}
else {
    echo $curl->response;
}

var_dump($curl->requestHeaders);
var_dump($curl->responseHeaders);
```

Oh, and it's an [unlicensed](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/blob/master/LICENSE) license type software.