# What's the diference between el.text and el.get_attribute('textContent') or innerHtml?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I came up with strange behavior of el.text, it started return nothing.
But before all works fine. I try el.get_attribute('innerHtml'), all works.
Elements are visible. Why it happens?

```
course_starts_dates =driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"]/td[2]/a')
for el in course_start_dates:
    course_start_date.append(el.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more a general XML issue. So it's important to know if your XML content changed.

in a short xml sample,

```
<xmlNode myAttr="value">
  <subElement1>Test </subElement1>
  <subElement1>123</subElement1>
</xmlNode>
```

innerText is a combination of all text within xmlNode (and so within subElement1 nodes). So it should return "Test 123"
The innerHTML should not return just the text, but also the XML/HTML tags within the result, e.g.

<subElement1>Test </subElement1>  <subElement1>123</subElement1>

The "text" is just the text value of xmlNode itself, when xmlNode has no children:

```
<xmlNode>Test 345</xmlNode>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you say me how I can whatch XML content of a website? To see this changes, as example.

Comment: XML is human readable with any text editor. If you can access the XML content by an URL, just call the URL in your web browser. Then you will already see the XML page in your browser. Here, click the "view page source" in your browser's context menu. You can save the xml content as .xml file. (Exact steps depend on the browser you use).

If you have different XML files, you could compare them with text compare utilities such as WinMerge.

If you don't have an URL to call your XML raw data, you have to find another way to access the xml data (e.g. when they are stored in a database)...

Comment: Check out the answer in [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199595/how-to-echo-xml-file-in-php) for an example how to directly print XML data in PHP when it's a server side file which you can't access locally.